# Best practice for configuration file in Visual studio F# solution

Tags: visual-studio, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I wonder if there is a best practice for seting up a configuration file in a F# solution.
Below is a sample of my configuration file, which is used by different projects in my F# solution.

myConfig.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Config>
      <Segment>  
        <SegmentTypes>
           <Did>did</Did>
           <PostCode>postcode</PostCode>
           <Ip>/ip</Ip>
       </SegmentTypes>

     </Segment>

     <SThreeConfig>
       <AccessKey>aaa</AccessKey>
       <SecretKey>bb</SecretKey>
     </SThreeConfig>

  </Config>
```

I could put the contain of the above in the built in App.config. As App.config does not allow nested
tags, it will become  messy as my configuration grows.

So far the best solution we have found is the following.
Create  a top level project configuration, and in that project,
   create a source file to read myConfig.xml using xml type provider.
   Then  wrap the values in myConfig.xml in static properties of 
   a class AppConfigObj.  The other projects in the solution will access  configuration properties 
   via appConfObj.

```
module Configuration=
   open FSharp.Data
   open System

   // Other projects acccess the configuration properties using AppConfigObj.
   type  AppConfigObj() =       
      static let [<Literal>] configXmlFile = "myConfig.xml"

      static let config = XmlProvider<configXmlFile>.Load(configXmlFile.ToString())

      static member didPath =  config.Segment.SegmentTypes.Did
      static member postcodePath = config.Segment.SegmentTypes.PostCode
      static member ipPath = config.Segment.SegmentTypes.Ip
      static member s3AccessKey = config.SThreeConfig.AccessKey    
      static member s3SecreteKey=config.SThreeConfig.SecretKey
```

Comment: "As App.config does not allow nested tags" Yes, it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx I would recommend using the default configuration mechanism for .NET, as it's tried and true. However, personally, if you need complex, nested configuration settings in the first place, it may be time to pause and reconsider: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.dk/2012/05/configuration-complexity-clock.html

Answer (score 3):

Although the default configuration mechanism is enough, there exists a very practical alternative which is using a config tailored type provider: [FSharp.Configuration](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/)

This way you work with typed classes for config and setting files.